# Horizontal Linear Progress Bar like Android in iOS

Tags: android, ios, swift3, progress-bar

How to do I implement a horizontal progress bar in iOS like as Android.

[image: Progressbar in iOS like Android]

I have tried the following, and found a solution like **deteminate**.

```
func startSendPickUpRequestShakeTimer () {

        if self.movingViewTimer == nil {
            self.movingViewTimer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(
                timeInterval: TimeInterval(movingViewSpeed),
                target      : self,
                selector    : #selector(self.startAnimating),
                userInfo    : nil,
                repeats     : true)
        }
}

func startAnimating() {

        let movingViewX = movingView.frame.minX >= view.frame.maxX ? 0-movingView.frame.width-forwardX:movingView.frame.minX + forwardX

        self.movingView.frame = CGRect(x: movingViewX, y: movingView.frame.minY, width: movingView.frame.width, height: moviewViewHeight)

}
```

But how can I implement the others, or is there any good resource to do that?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/linearprogressbar

Comment: Please follow the like :- **https://github.com/lfarah/LinearProgressBar** +Swift code

Comment: check out https://github.com/Marxon13/M13ProgressSuite and https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress

Answer (score 4):

I had coded this extension for indetermined progress in ios. Maybe this can help

```
extension UIProgressView{
    private struct Holder {
        static var _progressFull:Bool = false
        static var _completeLoading:Bool = false;
    }
    
    var progressFull:Bool {
        get {
            return Holder._progressFull
        }
        set(newValue) {
            Holder._progressFull = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var completeLoading:Bool {
        get {
            return Holder._completeLoading
        }
        set(newValue) {
            Holder._completeLoading = newValue
        }
    }
    
    func animateProgress(){
        if(completeLoading){
            return
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.setProgress(self.progressFull ? 1.0 : 0.0, animated: true)
        })
        
        progressFull = !progressFull;
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.2) {
            self.animateProgress();
        }
    }
    
    func startIndefinateProgress(){
        isHidden = false
        completeLoading = false
        animateProgress()
    }
    
    func stopIndefinateProgress(){
        completeLoading = true
        isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Fiverr: https://www.fiverr.com/kamranbashir

Comment: how do you change the animation time? I tried changing the duration from 1 to 10 and the 1.2 to 10.2 but that just made me wait 10.2 seconds between the animations.

Comment: Do you want to change the time it takes the bar to move from start to finish? Just change the withDuration:1 to withDuration:10.

The second one .now() + 1.2 is the time the thread waits before calling the animate progress. You can change this to increase the time between the animation.

Answer (score 0):

This is now part of Material components for iOS.
https://material.io/develop/ios/components/progress-indicators/progress-views

`pod 'MaterialComponents/ProgressView'`

`import MaterialComponents.MaterialProgressView`

Code sample:

```
    let progressView = MDCProgressView()
    progressView.mode = .indeterminate        
    progressView.progressTintColor = .white
    progressView.trackTintColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    progressView.startAnimating()
    
    view.addSubview(progressView)
    //Then set constraints for your view (I used SnapKit https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit)
    progressView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(header.snp.left)
        make.right.equalTo(header.snp.right)
        make.top.equalTo(header.snp.bottom).offset(20)
        make.height.equalTo(4)
    }
```

Comment: MDCProgressView doesn't seem to have the mode property itself. :(

Comment: I wouldn't use this pod anymore: `On July 15, 2021, Material's iOS libraries will enter maintenance mode.` as mentioned in the link.